# SQL Query taking long time with STUFF function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

Example Dataset:

```
ID  seat    code
15098   1   AA21
15098   2   AA21
15105   1   AA21
15105   1   DD15
15105   1   NN60
15196   1   AA21
15196   2   DD50
15196   2   DD51
15209   1   AA21
15209   3   AA21
15209   2   CC50
15209   1   DD01
15209   3   DD01
15210   1   AA21
15210   2   AA21
15210   3   AA21
15210   1   DD21
15210   2   DD21
15210   3   DD21
15211   1   CC51
15211   1   DD20
15212   1   AA21
15212   1   DD03
```

and Desired Result is:

```
ID  seat    Codes
15098   1    AA21
15098   2    AA21
15105   1    AA21, DD15, NN60
15196   1    AA21
15196   2    DD50, DD51
15209   1    AA21, DD01
15209   2    CC50
15209   3    AA21, DD01
15210   1    AA21, DD21
15210   2    AA21, DD21
15210   3    AA21, DD21
15211   1    CC51, DD20
15212   1    AA21, DD03
```

---

Example Dataset table query:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp(
ID varchar(50),
seat varchar(50), 
code varchar(150))

INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('15098', '1', 'AA21');
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('15098', '2', 'AA21');
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('15105', '1', 'AA21');
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('15105', '1', 'DD15');
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('15105', '1', 'NN60');
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('15196', '1', 'AA21');
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('15196', '2', 'DD50');
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('15196', '2', 'DD51');
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('15209', '1', 'AA21');
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('15209', '3', 'AA21');
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('15209', '2', 'CC50');
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('15209', '1', 'DD01');
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('15209', '3', 'DD01');
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('15210', '1', 'AA21');
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('15210', '2', 'AA21');
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('15210', '3', 'AA21');
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('15210', '1', 'DD21');
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('15210', '2', 'DD21');
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('15210', '3', 'DD21');
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('15211', '1', 'CC51');
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('15211', '1', 'DD20');
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('15212', '1', 'AA21');
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('15212', '1', 'DD03');
```

I am using below query as a part of my SSRS report stored procedure to get the result but it is taking too long to run as my original dataset is more than a 100000 rows. Is there any other efficient way to get the result.

```
SELECT 
 SS.ID
,SS.seat
,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(CR.Code)) AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
        FROM #Temp CR 
        WHERE CR.ID = SS.ID and CR.seat = SS.seat
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') Codes
FROM #Temp SS
GROUP BY SS.ID, SS.seat
```

Comment: Have you got an index on `ID` and `seat`? That'll help

Comment: #temp in my actual query is a view which is not an indexed view.

Comment: Is there an index on the underlying tables? That'll get expanded in the query processing. Check the actual execution plan to see where all the time is going.

Comment: I checked the execution plan of the view and it suggests to have a non clustered index on one of the underlying table but the problem is we are not allowed to create any indexes on the database as it is a SLA for the company with the software vendor. I am not sure how can i workaround that.

Comment: Worth shoving the data into a temp table or table variable, indexing, then querying. Might be slower, might be much faster, worth a go. If almost all of your rows have only a single Code you could try splitting into a CASE or UNION so you only run the XML PATH on the stuff that needs it ... but that seems like it shouldn't be better.

Comment: @Sqluser14 Try adding create non-clustered index on TEMP table, it won't affect the existing tables

Comment: Thank you for your comments Rory & User2012384. I created non clustered index on the temp table and it working awesome and very less time for the query execution. But the sad part is it seems like this is the half resolution for my problem. Report is still taking too much of time. But thank you for the help. Query level resolved with your suggestions.

Comment: NB: Your fields are varchar(50) and larger; but the sample data implies you're storing numbers and predefined codes; if that data's realistic you could further improve performance by refining the data types used.

Comment: one up vore for well explained question as well as with sample data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `Cross Apply` instead of `Correlated Sub-Query`

```
SELECT SS.ID,
       SS.seat,
       LEFT(cs.Codes, Len(cs.Codes) - 1) AS Region
FROM   #Temp SS
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT Code + ','
                    FROM   #Temp CR
                    WHERE  CR.ID = SS.ID
                           AND CR.seat = SS.seat
                    FOR XML PATH('')) cs (Codes)
GROUP  BY SS.ID,
          SS.seat,
          LEFT(cs.Codes, Len(cs.Codes) - 1)
```

Also create a `Non clustered index` on `ID and seat` including `code`

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_ProductVendor_VendorID
  ON #Temp (ID, seat)
  include (code)
```

**Execution Plan**

***Your query***

[image]

***Using Cross Apply***

[image]